# setName vs setId in Google App Script

Tags: google-apps-script

In 'google script', on trigger of an event (button click), I am trying to change the name as well as Id of a  textbox. Following is simplified code:

```
    function addRow(e){
      var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
      app.getElementById('tbox')
         .setId('txt1')
         .setName('txt1');
    }
```

Now, setId is working but setName is throwing me an error. Is there something that I am obviously missing?

Comment: Doesnt seem to make sense to change a dom item's id or name. Why would you want to do that? Strange.

Comment: Error is: `Error encountered: An unexpected error occurred`

Comment: That is only a sample code to show the logic. I am dynamically adding a table row in between and I want all the row elements below added row to update their names (to reflect their row number) so that I can fetch the values in them later. I think I will have to figure out a different way.

Comment: @Ram I guess you should leave the names and ids as simple increments, regardless of the position, and have a hidden widget or a simple `setTag` on the textbox where you save the current position on the screen.

Comment: @HenriqueAbreu I already did what you just suggested. But in larger context it makes my code really messy and need little more workarounds, but doesn't look like I have choice. Thank you again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From a quick test I did it seems that, although it does not throw an error if used alone, it is not possible to change an element's id, as shown in this little test:

```js
function doGet() {
  var app = UiApp.createApplication().setTitle('Button Test');
  return app.add(app.createTextBox().setId('tbox').setName('tbox').setText('tbox')
                 .addKeyPressHandler(app.createServerHandler('inspectBox'))).add(
    app.createButton('Change').addClickHandler(app.createServerHandler('btnClick')));
}

function inspectBox(e) {
  var p = e.parameter;
  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
  return app.add(app.createLabel('id: '+p.source)).add(
    app.createLabel('name: '+(p.tbox ? 'tbox' : p.txt1 ? 'txt1' : 'not found')));
}

function btnClick() {
  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
  app.getElementById('tbox').setId('txt1');
  //app.getElementById('tbox').setName('txt1');
  return app;
}
```

Later, if you comment the `setId` line and uncomment the `setName` one, then type a char in the textbox, you'll see that the name changes. And the `setName` call works fine if you continue working on the element using, for example, `setText`. Which is not true for `setId`, that fails if you try anything on the element.

Anyway, as commented by others, it's indeed odd that you have such a requirement. I guess you should find another way (possibly a better one) to do what you want (which you have not described).

Comment: Yes, if I uncomment the line with setName it works in my case too. I think I will have to find a work around.

Comment: @Ram Yes I guess this is a undocumented limitation: "can't change the id of an element already on screen". And since you're new in Stackoverflow, you should mark an answer as accepted when you feel you got a good one. It's a check mark near the voting arrows (another nice feature).